# Merging tags e-m and expectation-maximization

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The following two tags look synonymous:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expectation-maximization
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-m

Comment: [E-m] has only six questions. Somebody just needs to go ahead and  retag all six of them manually (perhaps you can do it, @Franck?). This is much simpler than to get moderators to make a tag synonym. After the tag is cleared off from all questions, it will be automatically deleted in 24 hours.

Comment: @amoeba sure, done

Comment: @Amoeba It is a simple matter for mods to make a tag synonym--which I have done. The beauty of that is it's *reversible*. It's much more difficult to reverse a systematic retagging. Upon checking the tag wikis, I discovered the wiki for the "e-m" tag stated "EM (expectation-maximization) is an iterative clustering algorithm that allows one to partition a data set into clusters based on the data's log-likelihood." That's much more specific than the wiki for [tag:expectation-maximization]. I wonder, then, whether those who used it did so expressly to indicate an interest in clustering.

Comment: @whuber I spotted that as well, but looking at the questions it was any kind of expectation maximization.

Comment: @whuber, that's right. The only reason I suggested to do this manually in this case, is that I have the feeling that moderators tend to be very reluctant to carry out any tag changes. I can easily point to several threads on meta where a tag change was suggested, got a very positive response (lots of upvotes, no downvotes or no negative comments), but no moderator  action was taken (kernel tag comes to mind, recent thread about nlp, etc). In fact, I was planning to ask a new meta question to draw attention to this issue and to discuss what should we do about it. Maybe it's a right time now!

Comment: @amoeba When mods are reluctant to make tag changes, perhaps that should be taken as a sign that such changes might be problematic. Manually forcing those changes through via wholesale edits to many posts doesn't seem like a constructive way to address that issue.  (BTW, I don't think any problems were created in this particular case.)

Comment: Yes, @whuber, I can see this point. I guess I will bring it up on meta as a separate question and then we can discuss it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this case seemed to be very clear-cut and as there were only very few (5) questions tagged with [e-m], I suggested to manually retag them to [expectation-minization] and have the issue solved.

This was done and the issue is solved.

I agree with @whuber, however, that in general massive manual retagging is something to avoid.